# \0 символ вместо русских букв .NET

Tags: c#, .net, строки, кодировка, input

При вводе текста буквами кириллицы вместо букв в строку записываются символы \0.

Ввожу "Привет", а записывается в переменную следующее:

[image: что оказывается в строке]

Пробовал менять кодировку, не помогло. Винда стоит на английском, может в этом проблема..

\0 в консоли выглядят как обычные пробелы.

Comment: Операционная система какая? Какая локализация стоит в операционной системе? `Console.WriteLine(Console.InputEncoding.EncodingName); Console.WriteLine(Console.OutputEncoding.EncodingName);` что выводит? Какой шрифт стоит в консоли?

Comment: Операционная система Windows 10 19041, локализация стоит английская.
Выводит UTF-8, шрифт Consolas 16

Comment: '''var str = Console.ReadLine();

            // Не работает
            Console.WriteLine(str);

            // Работает
            Console.WriteLine("Привет");'''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В русской винде по умолчанию в консоли стоит 866 кодовая страница. Если я выставляю UTF-8, то получаю такое же поведение, как у вас. Вы можете настроить кодовую страницу принудительно.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
    Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(866);
    Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(866);
    Console.WriteLine($"Input [{Console.InputEncoding.CodePage}] {Console.InputEncoding.EncodingName}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Output [{Console.OutputEncoding.CodePage}] {Console.OutputEncoding.EncodingName}");
    string s = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
Input [866] Cyrillic (DOS)
Output [866] Cyrillic (DOS)
привет, мир
привет, мир
```

Возможно прокатит, если вы только настроите `InputEncoding`, при этом можно не трогать `OutputEncoding`.

Comment: да, тут скорее проблема в вводе, а не в выводе, заработало с InputEncoding, спасибо