# Как сделать так, чтобы в консоли отображался русский язык?

Tags: c#, консоль

[image: Не могу разобраться с выводом текста на русском языке в консоли]
Не могу разобраться с выводом текста на русском языке в консоли

Comment: Файл в UTF8 сохранить попробуй.

Comment: попробуйте поменять шрифт в консоле нажав ПКМ по заголовку -> Свойства -> Шрифты. Не все шрифты поддерживают русский

Comment: @ГеннадийП какой файл? У него текст не в фале а в консоле вопросами

Comment: [Оно?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1278015/373567)

Comment: @KuzCode UTF8 - родная кодировка .NET. Если сохранить файл(и соответственно текст) в другой кодировке и пересобрать проект - будет выводить в соответствующей кодировке в консоль. Можно конечно поиграться с кодировкой консоли, но не проще ли решать корень проблемы, а не последствия?

Comment: @ГеннадийП корень проблемы здесь, очевидно, не русская ось, как следствие кодировка в консоли не 866. См. ссылку выше. Я бы уже закрыл как дубликат, но автор не подтверждает, оно или не оно.

Answer (score 0):

Пробуйте:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
//or
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
//or
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(866);
```

См.
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.console.outputencoding?view=net-5.0